# httpServer.listen() firing before http.createServer(). Why? How?

Tags: node.js

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log(`http.createServer..`);
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

"*Server running at http://localhost:3000/*" logged to console immediately after running the module.

"*http.createServer..*" logged to console on request to port 3000.

I would expect both `console.log`s to execute right away, in opposite order. In other words, for `createServer()` to run first, including the callback function and then to `.listen()`.

What is happening here?

EDIT: Documentation says the function within .createServer() is not a callback, but a requestListener - *a function which is automatically added to the 'request' event*. So, how does this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the request listener function (which you pass to createServer) is executed only when a request event is emitted.

From the  [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener)

> The requestListener is a function which is automatically added to the 'request' event.

The request event

> Emitted each time there is a request. Note that there may be multiple requests per connection (in the case of HTTP Keep-Alive connections).

Comment: Ha! Yes, thanks, Ive discovered this just as you have posted this. So I guess, when I want a mySQL connection to be ready for handling incoming request, I should set it up in the callback function of .listen() ?

Comment: I would instead start the http server only after the mySQL connection has been completed.

Comment: Ok, could you give me an example, pls